# Работа со строками и последовательностями цифр в C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, winforms

не мог бы кто-нибудь помочь с задачей: 
Дан текст с буквами и цифрами, найти группы цифр (2 и более) и на место этих групп цифр записать число- кол-во цифр ( в каждом слове отдельное). Сам пробовал, но что-то алгоритма никакого придумать не в состоянии . Вот код:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = Source_Text.Text,textus=string.Empty;
        int start = 0, end = 0,  total_amount=0;
        string[] words = text.Split(' ');
        for(int i=0;i<words.Length;i++)
        {
            start = 0;
            end = 0;
            // Ищу начало последовательности цифр
        while (start < words[i].Length - 1 && !char.IsNumber(words[i], start))
                start++;

            end = start;
            //Ищу конец последовательности цифр
            while (end < words[i].Length - 2 && char.IsNumber(words[i], end))
                end++;
            if(start!=end)
            {
                total_amount++;
                words[i].Insert(start, Convert.ToString(end));
                words[i].Remove(start + 1, end);
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            Modifed_Text.Text = words[i];
    }
```

Comment: Напишите алгоритм словами на бумаге.

Comment: Я изначально всё на бумаге и написал, но он (алгоритм) опять же не самый лучший, проблему составляет только нахождение групп цифр, если их в слове несколько, то это уже проблема, опыта пока мало, вот и попросил помощи, спасибо за то, что дали дельный совет.

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Вам нужно следующее? Найти числа в словах. Если в слове больше или равоно 2 числам, значит на место этих числ ставить числа их количества? Допустим текст "вс1е23м привет, м100ен2я зовут нак". То текст должен быть таким "вс2е2м привет, м2ен2я зовут нак". Тоесть в каждом слове все числа заменены на числа, которые обозначают их количество в слове?

Comment: Да, именно так, но за исключением того, что должно получиться, что-то типа 
"вс1е2м привет,м3ен2я зовут нак", т.е. считаются лишь группы цифр, если они не стоят рядом,т.е. не сгруппированы, то их надо оставить как есть.

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял задачу, то примерно так:

```
var temp = "вс1е23м привет, м100ен2я зовут нак";
foreach (Match m in new Regex("[0-9]{2,}").Matches(temp))
    temp = temp.Replace(m.Value, m.Value.Length.ToString());
```